# Expresion regular numeros con un decimal JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Dado un texto con las siguientes líneas:

```
      1          01/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            11,4
      1          02/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            13,8
      1          03/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            13,9
      1          04/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            13,5
      1          05/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            4,2
      1          06/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            4,1
      1          07/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            4,4
      1          08/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            7,1
      1          09/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            9
      1          10/01/2018    Temperatura mínima a 1.5m (ºC)            6,7
```

Necesito una expresión regular utilizando **referencias inversas** para obtener la última columna, la de los números.

Necesito un patrón parecido al siguiente, pero que obtenga todos los numeros independientemente de si tienen o no decimales:

```
(Temperatura\smínima\sa\s1.5m\s\(ºC\)).*((\w\w,\w))
```

Se utilizará en un futuro para asignarlselo a una variable, y así obtener la posicion del patrón.

```
var patron = (Temperatura\smínima\sa\s1.5m\s\(ºC\)).*((\w\w,\w));

console.log(patron[3]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es para la última columna, puedes usar algo como esto:

(\d+[,]?\d?)$

El carácter $ implica el final de la linea y el \d dígito puedes sustituir la d por una w si estás más interesado en caracteres.

Saludos.